# Elasticsearch java api error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j

I am using java elasticsearch 5.4 api. When I run sample program I am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.<init>(AbstractXContentParser.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.<init>(JsonXContentParser.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createParser(JsonXContent.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.parseableStringToList(Setting.java:848)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.lambda$listSetting$27(Setting.java:802)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:807)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:802)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:101)
    at com.ibm.esclient.ESClient.main(ESClient.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

My dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8
            </version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Basically I have tried to add all possible log4j loggers here but to no avail. Quite frustrating, need help please!!

Comment: Some of those dependencies are outdated. For instance logback-classic is at version 1.2.3.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Still the same!

Answer (score 2):

A small mistake led to this error. I had specified  as test. I removed it and this started working

Answer (score 0):

Just in case - if logging was configured properly and problem only occurs after adding ES dependency would not it be easier solution to just add exclusion for ES log4j dependency (instead of adding more loggers)?

In gradle it's something like:

```
compile ('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.2.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j'
}
```

Solves NoClassDefFoundError exceptions just fine.